# Count how many times a data-attribute or text string exists in a string and return the number for each one

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a little PHP & JavaScript app that cURL requests a list of URLs and writes to a log file when any URL in that list of URLs returns a, 404 or 500 status code for example.

Ok what I am trying to do is count with JavaScript how many of each URL exists in the log file and return the number. I want to return a structure kind of like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>http://www.example.com  (5)</li>
    <li>http://anothersite.org (19)</li>
    <li>http://www.more.com    (16)</li>
</ul>
```

In the log file I have given each URL entry a data-attribute and looks like this:

```
<p class="log-text">
    <span data-url="www.examplezz.com">www.examplezz.com - 0 (Timeout)</span> 
    <span data-url="www.examplezz.com/othersite">www.examplezz.com/othersite - 0 (Timeout)</span>
    <span data-url="www.idontexist.io">www.idontexist.io - 0 (Timeout)</span> 
    <span data-url="www.idontexist.io/othersite">www.idontexist.io/othersite - 0 (Timeout)</span> 
</p>
<p class="log-text">
    <span data-url="www.examplezz.com">www.examplezz.com - 0 (Timeout)</span> 
    <span data-url="www.examplezz.com/othersite">www.examplezz.com/othersite - 0 (Timeout)</span>
    <span data-url="www.idontexist.io">www.idontexist.io - 0 (Timeout)</span> 
    <span data-url="www.idontexist.io/othersite">www.idontexist.io/othersite - 0 (Timeout)</span>
</p>
<p class="log-text">
    <span data-url="www.examplezz.com">www.examplezz.com - 0 (Timeout)</span> 
</p>
```

The log file is fetched via ajax, and I get it as a string. Here is a JS Bin  with the "for" loop I have been trying to work with:

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/adEBiCU/2/edit?js,console,output)

Additional info: Here is what my ajax request looks like, not sure if it helps.

```
var overLoad = function (){
    $.ajax({  
    type: 'POST',  
    url: 'includes/logfiles/'+logfilename+'.php',
    data: $('.log-text'),
    statusCode: {
      404: function() {
        $("<p class='intro log-text eventNum' style='margin-bottom:0;'>Is your internet connection intact?</p>").appendTo(".overview-popup");
      }
    }   
    }).done(function (data) {

            // here I want to count the urls in the 'data' string

     }).fail(function (jqXHR, statusCode) {
      $("<p class='intro log-text eventNum' style='margin-bottom:0;'>No offline events!</p>").appendTo(".overview-popup");
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why try to do string manipulation when you have the DOM at your finger tips?

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = data;
var elements = div.querySelectorAll('[data-url]');
var urls = {};

for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var url = elements[i].getAttribute('data-url');

    if(!(url in urls)) {
        urls[url] = 0;
    }

    urls[url]++;
}

console.log(urls);
```

http://jsbin.com/adEBiCU/3/edit

I leave the grouping by host name (instead of just url) to you as an exercise. Hint: use the DOM (double hint: `<a>` has a `host` property).

Edit: I missed that you're already using jQuery.

```
var data ='<p class="log-title">not available. <span class="stamp"><span >Pinged: </span>Wednesday 1st of January 2014 03:57:03 PM</span></p><p class="log-text"><span data-url="www.examplezz.com">www.examplezz.com - 0 (Timeout)</span><br /><span data-url="www.examplezz.com/othersite">www.examplezz.com/othersite - 0 (Timeout)</span><br /><span data-url="www.idontexist.io">www.idontexist.io - 0 (Timeout)</span><br /><span data-url="www.idontexist.io/othersite">www.idontexist.io/othersite - 0 (Timeout)</span><br /></p>';

var urls = $(data).find('[data-url]').map(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
    return $('<a>', {href: 'http://' + url})[0].host;
}).get().reduce(function(urls, b) {
        if(!(b in urls)) {
    urls[b] = 0;
    }

    urls[b]++;

    return urls;
}, {});


console.log(urls);
```

http://jsbin.com/adEBiCU/5/edit

Comment: This is great, simple and vanilla:) Thank you very much for your response .

Comment: You're welcome. I actually like the vanilla version more than the jQuery version. The url -> host mapping would be as simple as well.

Comment: Wow think I just realised what you meant by "Why try to do string manipulation when you have the DOM at your finger tips?" ha. Thanks again.

Comment: In answer to your exercise for me, this is what I did:`for (var key in urls) {
          if (urls.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            console.log(key + " -> " + urls[key]);
            }
          }`

Comment: That's not what I meant. I thought you wanted to map `www.examplezz.com/othersite` to `www.examplezz.com`.

Comment: Ah ok my bad, I misunderstood. I actually want to count "www.examplezz.com/othersite and www.examplezz.com" as separate entries. But I think in your jQuery example you gave me a big hint as to the host grouping,  `return $('<a>', {href: 'http://' + url})[0].host;`

Comment: If by hint you mean solution, then yes :-D. It's an in-memory anchor element and I'm accessing its `host` property.